# What does the verb phrase 'exposed to' mean?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

In this following context, what does the verb phrase 'exposed to' mean?

Does it mean 'experienced'?

Context:

> Without birth there cannot be decay and death. If we had not been
> born, we would not have to die, and would not be **exposed to** all sorts
> of misery.

Source: P. 41
''The Fundamentals of Buddhism"
by Nyanatiloka Mahathera

Comment: Have you consulted any dictionaries? If so, please [edit] your question to include what you found and what you're still unsure about. Otherwise, this question is off-topic for lack of research.

Comment: Note the *passive* verb form. A person being *exposed* to attack means there is a *risk* of him being attacked (even if he doesn't actually *get* attacked). But if he *experiences* an attack, that means he's *definitely* been attacked for real! In practice in your cited context, though, we all *do* experience the misery that we're exposed to. [Into each life a little rain must fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_Each_Life_Some_Rain_Must_Fall), and all that. (And I *still* think he/they should have written/sung ***A Little***, not ***Some**!* :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the whole text [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanatiloka/wheel394.html).  The context of that sentence is when the author explains proposition #11, part of the explanation of *paticca-samuppada* which

> shows the causes and conditions of all the suffering in the world; and how, through the removal of these conditions, suffering may rise no more in the future.

About proposition #11:

> Now we have reached the eleventh and last proposition: *Jati-paccaya jara-maranam*: "Through rebirth decay and death are conditioned." Without birth there cannot be decay and death. If we had not been born, we would not have to die, and would not be **exposed** to all sorts of misery. Thus rebirth is a necessary condition for decay and death, and for all other forms of misery. Hence it was said: "Through rebirth decay and death are conditioned."

Because the context is about removal of the causes and conditions of an individual's suffering in the world, "exposed" here mean **vulnerable** / **susceptible**.

Other examples of "exposed" in this meaning:

- If we go out in the rain without bringing an umbrella, we will be "exposed" to being wet.
- If we put all our money in stocks, we will be "exposed" to the risk of market crashing.
- Etc.